# scrollview not scrolling with full screen mode

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, scrollview

> I want to scroll the whole screen with hiding title bar and I have requested full screen programmatically before setContentView ....but this request prevents scrollview to scroll ...
>
> below I have provided style XML, and Activity code wherein I request fullScreen and fragment.XML where I am facing the scrollling problem

**style.xml**

```
 <resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/MyDrawerArrowToggle</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>

</style>

<style name="MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>


</style>

<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen">
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
</style>


<!-- Actionbar Theme -->
<style name="ActionBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>

<style name="MyDrawerArrowToggle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="color">@color/white</item>

</style>

<style name="MyDrawerTitle" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="color">@color/black</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

<style name="EditText.Login" parent="Widget.AppCompat.EditText">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@android:color/darker_gray</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.MaterialProgressBar.ProgressBar" parent="android:Widget.ProgressBar">
    <item name="android:indeterminateDrawable">@null</item>
    <item name="android:minWidth">48dp</item>
    <item name="android:maxWidth">48dp</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">48dp</item>
    <item name="android:maxHeight">48dp</item>
</style>


<color name="black">#000000</color>
<color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>
```

**java code**

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        changeFragment(new WelcomeFragment(), "");
    }

    public void changeFragment(final Fragment fragment, final String fragmenttag) {

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, fragment, fragmenttag);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            }
        }, 0);

    }
```

**fragment xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_30dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tv_notification"

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:lines="1"
                    android:padding="@dimen/margin_5dp"
                    android:text="------------------" />

                <TextView

                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="@dimen/margin_5dp"
                    android:text="Notification"
                    android:textColor="@color/black" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="@dimen/margin_5dp"
                    android:text="-----------------" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_error"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:padding="@dimen/margin_5dp"
                android:text="You Got No Notification"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_error1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="----------------------------------------------------------"
                android:visibility="gone" />

              <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
                    android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="250dp">

                    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent">

                        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                            android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:visibility="visible" />


                    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
                </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>





            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linear_main"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_20dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="visible">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"

                    android:padding="@dimen/margin_10dp"
                    android:text="Number to Navigate to"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/margin_18sp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_phone"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_40dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:hint="Enter Number"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/margin_18sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="@dimen/margin_10dp"

                    android:text="OR"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/margin_18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/et_contact"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_40dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:hint="Choose From Contact"
                    android:inputType="phone"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/margin_18sp" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
                    android:id="@+id/btn_access"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_20dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/request_access"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: make your Scrollview **android:fillViewport="true"**

Comment: didn't work ......

Answer (score 2):

add this into the ScrollView :

```
android:fillViewport="true"
```

You can add this property to your activity:

```
<activity
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"
....
/>
```

Comment: Try Nested Scrollview on Parent.

Comment: @AshutoshTripathi ok  i m waiting

Comment: haa?? @AshutoshTripathi  how did u check .. making new project ? if yes then i give u email id send me that proj

Comment: @AshutoshTripathi  what happnd?